# Flash Builder Code completion for events

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml, flash-builder

When I'm using a built-in `EventDispatcher` the code completion will show a list of all events that are fired by the class, example:

[image: Code Completion - Built In Class]

How can I achieve the same for my own classes, for example I might extend the event class like this:

```
import flash.events.Event;

public class MyEvent extends Event
{

    //Event Types
    public static const FIRST_EVENT:String = 'firstEvent';
    public static const SECOND_EVENT:String = 'secondEvent';

    //Construct
    public function MyEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
    {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    }
}
```

And then I might write an `EventDispatcher` like this:

```
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;

public class MyEventDispatcher extends EventDispatcher
{
    public function foo() :void{
        dispatchEvent(new MyEvent(MyEvent.FIRST_EVENT));
    }

    public function bar() :void{
        dispatchEvent(new MyEvent(MyEvent.SECOND_EVENT));
    }

}
```

**What can I do to make my events appear in the code completion box?**

I am aware that I can use metadata above the class, like this:

```
[Event(name="firstEvent", type="my.MyEvent")]
[Event(name="secondEvent", type="my.MyEvent")]
```

But that is only good for MXML, and the code completion only knows about the string value (`"firstEvent"`), but not the const (`MyEvent.FIRST_EVENT`).

I am using Flash Builder 4.7.

Comment: Did a quick search, this may help: http://labs.almerblank.com/2010/07/flash-builder-%E2%80%93-custom-event-code-hinting/

Comment: The only way is in your answer. FB translate the string event name, that you indicate in metatag, from "camel style" _myCustomEvent_ to "upper case style" MY_CUSTOM_EVENT, so you should remember this when give the name to the event and string value for it.

Comment: @fsbmain: You are right, also I found that FB will actually check that the const exists and that the value is correct before showing the hint.

Comment: @puggsoy: Thanks, link was helpful. I will start to use th asdoc syntax aswell